# listview.separator showing blank screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, listview

listview.separator not showing any items only blank screen, the list is linked with firestore storage... is my code even right?? please help

```
class _SpecialOffersState extends State<SpecialOffers> {
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userStream =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('med_cntr').snapshots();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: [
   
    SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenWidth(5)),
    
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _userStream,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 150.0,
            child: ListView.separated(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              itemCount: 10,
              separatorBuilder: (context, idx) {
                return SizedBox(width: 12);
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Image.network(
                          snapshot.data?.docs[index]['coverArt'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                end: Alignment.topCenter,
                                colors: [
                                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                                  Colors.transparent
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 8,
                        left: 8,
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data?.docs[index]['name'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

errors shown in the console:

1. RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
2. Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

Comment: Before asking a question please check for similar problems in StackOverflow or google it. First read the error message, it is clear that your column has an infinite height. Wrap the Column with Sizedbox and set height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `Expanded` outside `ListView` and set **height** - **width** for card

try:

```
class _SpecialOffersState extends State<SpecialOffers> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userStream =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('med_cntr').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [

        SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenWidth(5)),

        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _userStream,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return SizedBox(
              height: 150.0,
              child: ListView.separated(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                itemCount: 10,
                separatorBuilder: (context, idx) {
                  return SizedBox(width: 12);
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      ),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: Image.network(
                              snapshot.data?.docs[index]['coverArt'],
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 0,
                            left: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            child: Container(
                                height: 80.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                                    colors: [
                                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                                      Colors.transparent
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 8,
                            left: 8,
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data?.docs[index]['name'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ); 
  }
}
```